# SQL query joining tables - subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to all the documents from alldocs (where siteid=something and checkout is not null). Alldocs has a fields call checkoutuserid and I need to get the name from the userinfo table. UserInfo may have same ID repeated and that's why I am adding site-id. I am getting an error on the following query. "Subquery returned more than 1 value)

```
SELECT AllDocs.LeafName
     , AllDocs.CheckoutDate
     , UserInfo.tp_Title AS [User Name]
     , UserInfo.tp_Login AS [User ID]
     , UserInfo.tp_Email
FROM AllDocs
INNER JOIN UserInfo ON AllDocs.CheckoutUserId = (
        SELECT UserInfo.tp_ID
        FROM UserInfo
        WHERE UserInfo.tp_SiteID = 'E2FF98A7-B719-428D-8C30-856F08989691'
    )
WHERE (AllDocs.SiteId = 'E2FF98A7-B719-428D-8C30-856F08989691')
    AND (AllDocs.CheckoutUserId IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY AllDocs.LeafName
```

I am adding following working code as I have added a 3rd table to the query. The following is working perfectly.

```
use WSS_Content_MMRHome1
SELECT     distinct AllDocs.LeafName AS [File Name], AllDocs.dirName AS [Path], AllDocs.CheckoutDate, 
           UserInfo.tp_Title AS [User Name], UserInfo.tp_Login AS [User ID], 
           UserInfo.tp_Email AS [User Email], AllLists.tp_Title AS [List Name], ('http://inside.nv.com/'+AllDocs.DirName+'/'+AllDocs.LeafName) AS URL
FROM       AllDocs 
           INNER JOIN UserInfo ON AllDocs.CheckoutUserId = UserInfo.tp_ID AND UserInfo.tp_SiteID = AllDocs.SiteId
           INNER JOIN AllLists ON AllDocs.ListId = AllLists.tp_ID
WHERE      AllDocs.SiteId = 'D36CCEA0-5351-4AEC-8B83-ACA2439CF38B'
                AND AllDocs.CheckoutUserId IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY AllDocs.LeafName
```

Comment: If it's supposed to be more than one value, use `in` instead of `=` -- or fix your sql to fetch only one value. You could also use `and exists (select 1...` structure, it's usually better for performance and nulls don't cause issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the subquery, just move the additional criteria to the `join` (or include in the `where` clause):

```
SELECT     distinct AllDocs.LeafName, AllDocs.CheckoutDate, 
           UserInfo.tp_Title AS [User Name], UserInfo.tp_Login AS [User ID], 
           UserInfo.tp_Email
FROM       AllDocs INNER JOIN
           UserInfo ON AllDocs.CheckoutUserId = UserInfo.tp_ID 
                AND UserInfo.tp_SiteID = 'E2FF98A7-B719-428D-8C30-856F08989691'
WHERE      AllDocs.SiteId = 'E2FF98A7-B719-428D-8C30-856F08989691'
                AND AllDocs.CheckoutUserId IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY AllDocs.LeafName
```

---

Actually looks like the same site id?  If so, just join on that field as well:

```
...
FROM       AllDocs INNER JOIN
           UserInfo ON AllDocs.CheckoutUserId = UserInfo.tp_ID 
                AND UserInfo.tp_SiteID = AllDocs.SiteId
WHERE      AllDocs.SiteId = 'E2FF98A7-B719-428D-8C30-856F08989691'
                AND AllDocs.CheckoutUserId IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY AllDocs.LeafName
```

Comment: Probably true, but this *could* generate duplicate rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- true, depends on the desired results at that point.  Distinct might help in that case...

Comment: this gives me duplicate rows from alldocs. but if I add distinct it solves the issue

Comment: @sgeddes: Thanks for the speedy reply. It worked as desired. I appreciate it.